# How to Create a webservice by Qt

Tags: c++, qt, web-services, qtwebkit

I am looking for a tool or plugin that help me to create web service as DOT NET does for Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OP Edit in question:

> After search, I found that Qt does not have any thing to write web
>   services
>
> [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) is an Open Source Solution for this problem, currently we use
>   it.

Answer (score 2):

look at [libqxt](http://libqxt.org). It's a framework for building and using webservices.

Comment: Thanks. but I need a reliable solution. this is beta version.
Do you have another solution ?

Comment: @behrouz: Who says it's beta?

Comment: :-D ...in the opensource world, even a 0.1.0 version is more stable and reliable than a 1.0 version of a commercial product! trust me, I'm earning my money with commercial development for more than 10 years - and a 1.0 release is just a marketing thing, not a prove of stability ;-)

Comment: Are you aware of any tutorials or examples creating a WebService with this library. It is nice to know all classes and functions as of http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/index.html , but an example would be of great help for me.